# get_bloginfo doesnt be centered

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

my get_bloginfo ( It is wordpress code which calls the text of "My WordPress Blog" ) doesnt be centered.Here is the codes:

```
  <!-- header -->
        <header class="header clear" role="banner">

                <!-- logo -->
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
                        <!-- svg logo - toddmotto.com/mastering-svg-use-for-a-retina-web-fallbacks-with-png-script -->
                        <img  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.svg" alt="Logo" class="logo-img">
                    </a>

                </div>
            <div class="strip"></div>
            <div class="slogan"><?php echo get_bloginfo($show='description'); ?></div>
                <!-- /logo -->

                <!-- nav -->
                <nav class="nav" role="navigation">
                    <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
                </nav>
                <!-- /nav -->

        </header>

.logo-img {
display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.strip {
    margin-top:-30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #cf9008 50%, #cf9008 50%, #cf9008 100%);
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.slogan {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
```

the link:

http://www.themeforest-deneme2.deniz-tasarim.site/2020/01/03/fhhfh/

Comment: `.slogan {
    display:block;}` since you are using auto margins on sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.slogan {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

this is your css code. Change **display:inline-block** property to **display:block**

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
.slogan {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center
}
```

To:

```
.slogan {
    text-align: center
}
```